# Assign array to object

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm migrating my app from AngularJs to Angular 4.

I have used following type of statements very often in my code by they all are failing in Angular 4 (TypeScript):

**Edit: Following lines were used in AngularJS**

```
var accomodation = {};
accomodation.AccomodationAddresses = [];
```

I tried this in my component **class in Angular4**:

```
this.accomodation = {};
this.accomodation.AccomodationAddresses = [];
```

It gives error:  Property AccomodationAddresses does not exist :(

Comment: it looks so wrong, first dont use var, 2nd where do you declare those variables? as members of the class? as local vars for a function?

Comment: @DanielNetzer var accomodation is from AngularJS

Comment: I know, but its a forbidden word in TS, and something you should avoid cause of the transpiling process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript uses inference from assignment to determine the type of a variable.

You can either use any to get out of the type system altogether (not a great option) :

```
let accommodation : any = {};
accomodation.AccomodationAddresses = [];
```

Or you can be explicit about the type of the variable:

```
let accommodation : { AccomodationAddresses?: any[] } = {}; // used any but you can use a more explicit type
accomodation.AccomodationAddresses = [];
```

Or use a named interface:

```
interface Accomodation { AccomodationAddresses?: any[] } // used any but you can use a more explicit type
let accommodation : Accomodation  = {};     accomodation.AccomodationAddresses = [];
```

If it is feasible you can also initialize it all at once and have TS infer the correct type:

```
let accomodation = { AccomodationAddresses: [] }
```

Comment: why use var? why not let/const? where do you declare those variables?

Comment: @DanielNetzer changed it to let, but it was not essential to the question at hand

Comment: Or just initialize everything at once: `accomodation = { AccomodationAddresses: [] };`.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes that is another option, i'll add it :)

Comment: ofc. it is, part of an answer is showing the OP the right way to write code.